# Imagen de fondo figura primero al hacer onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css, imagen, hover

Buenas no entiendo porque me figura la imagen de fondo al hacer onclick en una imagen es como si la opacidad me este dando en ambas fotos.
Este es el div que contiene la imagen

```
<div class="imgs" id="imgs"><img src="img/24.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" class="image" alt="img1" onClick="imgvis(1)" id="image"/></div>
```

y este es la funcion cuando hace onclick

```
var src = document.getElementById("image").src;
                document.getElementById("divhidden").style.visibility="visible";
                document.getElementById("backimg").src=src;
```

y este el div que contiene la imagen que se abre

```
<div class="container2" id="divhidden" style="height: 963px;" onClick="imgvis(0)">
            <figure class="figure">
                <img width="100%" height="100%" id="backimg">
            </figure>
```

CSS

```css
/*DIV que contiene image*/
.imgs:hover {
    width: 25%;
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    height: 557px;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: left;
 background-color: orangered;
}
/*imagen*/
.image:hover{
 opacity: 0.8;
 cursor: zoom-in;

}
/*Figure*/
.figure{
    width: 30%;
    text-align: center;
 position: fixed;
}
/* container 2 que contiene figure y imagen a mostrar al hacer click*/
.container2{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    align-items: center;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
 visibility: hidden;
 cursor: zoom-out;
}
```

queda asi   [image: Imagen al hacer click]
al sacar el puntero de la imagen queda bien 
[image: imagen al sacar el puntero de la imagen]

Answer (score 0):

No creo entender muy bien como estás formulando tu pregunta, pero según entiendo leyendo el código, quieres que al hacer click en una imagen ésta se sustituya en el div `divhidden`

```js
function imgvis(e){
  var src = e.src;
  document.getElementById("divhidden").style.visibility="visible";
  document.getElementById("backimg").src=src;
}
```

```html
<div class="imgs" id="imgs"><img src="https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/smiley-icon-30.png"  class="image" alt="img1" onClick="imgvis(this)" id="image"/></div>

<div class="imgs" id="imgs"><img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/scream-queens/images/5/52/White-smiley-face-png-white_frowning_face_u2639_icon_256x256.png/revision/latest?cb=20160627203959"  class="image" alt="img1" onClick="imgvis(this)" id="image"/></div>
<hr>

<div class="container2" id="divhidden" style="height: 963px;" onClick="imgvis(0)">
            <figure class="figure">
                <img width="100%" height="100%" id="backimg">
            </figure>
```

Comment: Claro y que el div hidden se haga visible eso lo puedo logra lo que no entiendo porque es que al hacer eso la imagen del divhidden se ve  con opacidad por el hover de la imagen del div al cual se le hace click no se si se entiende

Comment: La verdad no se entiende muy bien, podrías editar tu pregunta agregando imagenes del problema? y si puedes agregar las clases `container2` y `figure` de tu css

Comment: lo que no entiendo es porque al hacer click en la imagen, me sale como si fuera con opacidad en esa parte de la imagen